# elpa/melpa autoload package

Tags: package-repositories

I new with elpa/melpa, and can not understand: 
should package (installed from melpa repository) be autoload by emacs during start or not?

I install 'company' from melpa repo, and `(require 'company)` in my ".emacs" failed:
LANG=C emacs --debug-init show such error:

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "company")
>    require(company)
>    eval-buffer(# nil "/home/user/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at 
>   buffer position 9609

position 9609 is exactly where `(require 'company)` ends.

At the same time, when I install "magit" from melpa, all work fine without ".emacs" modification.

So after I install something using `M-x list-packages` and restart emacs, should
installed package be autoload by default?
If they should be autoload, why company have different behavior?

I used GNU Emacs 24.5.1

Comment: 'when I install "magit" from melpa, all work fine without ".emacs" modification' - so you don't have `(require 'magit)` in your .emacs?

Comment: Yes, I use diff-hl and magit from melpa, and no note about them in .emacs

Comment: (package-initialize) at the top of .emacs helps, but not clear why magit and diff-hl works without them.

Comment: I think it's explained in the answer the at the dup target, but basically, Emacs calls `(package-initialize)` after loading your .emacs if you haven't done so.

Answer (score 0):

> (require 'company) in my ".emacs" failed

How did it fail? What message do you get? (See the messages buffer).

> If they should be autoload, why company have different behavior?

It is standard as far as I can tell. Install from `M-x list-packages` and then `M-x company-mode` to enable it. No need to edit .emacs.d or init.el files unless you want to customize. See [usage](http://company-mode.github.io) section of company mode's main web page for more details.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is missing `package-initialize`

Comment: @lawlist Probably not since the OP mentions magit works from a melpa install.

Comment: added note about failure message for require company to main post

Comment: I have several different packages, for example diff-hl, and "diff-hl" works after start without any ".emacs" modification, but not write any where about `package-initialize` in my .emacs